# sharepoint online list calculated column cannot see columns from the site columns list in site settings?

Tags: sharepoint-online

I'm pretty new to SharePoint Online, but use it in a fairly basic way to hold documents, lists and planners and various subsites etc.

From the POV of an SPO List, I realised quick quickly it was beneficial to create these in the main sites 'Site Settings, then Site Columns' area, so that the same created column and its configuration could be added again to another SPO list (as opposed to having to recreate the same thing over again from scratch).

Problem I've just discovered however, is that when I then went to use a column with a 'Calculated (calculation based on other columns)' value within any one individual SPO list, the list of columns shown within the configuration page associated to this only shows that of the columns within that one SPO list (ie, it *does not* show the columns created higher up the hierarchy in the 'Site Settings, then Site Columns' list.

Is there a way to enable the Calculated Column value 'see' the columns created in the 'Site Settings, then Site Columns' list?

Thanks in advance

Adam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SharePoint list columns based on site columns can very much be used in Calculated columns. In the following screenshot, the highlighted columns are defined as site columns.

However, not all column data types are available to calculated columns. That may be the true reason why you don't see the columns names in the definition dialog: These data types cannot be used in a calculated column, for e.g. Person or Group, Lookup, Managed Metadata, etc. Columns that store complex objects are not available in calculated columns.

[image]

Comment: Hi Teyln, the strangest thing...... having now gone and looked again they are indeed appearing in the list of columns?! Would there potentially be a period of replication or something that might mean they wouldn't appear immediately after creation at site level? Either way, I'm a happy boy now!